# clone git repo's in order using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to clone 3 git repos specified in a config yml using ansible, for that I have used the below code

```
- name: clone all the git repos
  git:
    repo: "{{ item.repo }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    version: "{{ item.branch }}"
    force: yes
    depth: 1
  loop: "{{ config.git }}"
```

Below is the config.yml,

```
  git:
    - dest: /home/Desktop/repo1
      name: repo1
      repo: gitlab***
      branch: master
    - dest: /home/Desktop/repo2
      name: repo2
      repo: gitlab***
      branch: master
    - dest: /home/Desktop/repo3
      name: repo3
      repo: gitlab***
      branch: master
```

Now I am trying to clone the repos in **order**. Example: first repo2 and then the rest of the repos. I couldn't find so any solution or advice is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using the file name as a key in the loop statement, you need to use git

Comment: what is the criteria for sorting the list of git repos? you can add a new field - called "priority" - and then follow the answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864288/sort-dict-according-to-specific-value-in-ansible

Answer (score 0):

I used this workaround, this loop will initially clone repo1 and then clone the rest avoiding repo1 from loop. This has solved my problem

```
loop:
     - "repo1"
     - "{{ config.git | ternary(omit, 'repo1') }}"
```